# how to pass void * (pointing to double or int) from C to C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

I have general callback type in C:

```
typedef int(*OverrideFieldValueSetCB_t)(const char *Dialog, const char *FieldName, void *Value);
```

and callback:

```
OverrideFieldValueSetCB_t       gOverrideFieldValueSetCB;
```

and function I call in C-code to pass value to C# :

```
int DllGuiSetFieldValue(const char *Dialog, const char *FieldName, void *pValue)
{   
    return gOverrideFieldValueSetCB(Dialog, FieldName, pValue);
}
```

In C# code I set this kind of delegate:

```
private static int OverrideFieldValueSetCb(string dialogName, string fieldName, IntPtr value)
{
    ///...
}
```

In above I would like to marshal/cast value to int or double depending on fieldName.

Questions:

1. Is IntPtr correct?
2. If IntPtr is correct, how to cast/marshal it to double or int ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pointing to double or int" is just asking for trouble.

But if you're certain that's the way you want to go, have a look at the `Marshal` class - `Marshal.ReadInt32` for `int`, and `Marshal.PtrToStructure<double>` for `double`. Make sure you don't mess the two up :)

Of course, if you can use `unsafe` code, you don't need to use `Marshal`. Just do the cast as you would in C.

Example:

```
double val = 123.45d;
double second;
double third;

unsafe
{
  void* ptr = &val;

  second = *(double*)ptr;
  third = Marshal.PtrToStructure<double>(new IntPtr(&val));
}

second.Dump();
```

Comment: Usually the Marshal will cause an `Exception` if you try to convert something that doesn't fit... still I hope you do not shoot wild pointers around the memory arbitrarily.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Yeah, but that rarely saves you in practice for something as small as `int` or `double` - and on 64-bit, both are often 64-bit aligned anyway, so... :D You'll mostly just get silly data, though that can already mean a security problem, for example.

Comment: indeed. I still hope the question was in that manner, that he'd have to convert an integer value and a double value that are independent of each other.

Comment: I found another solution (see my answer) so I didn't try this: Marshal.PtrToStructure<double>. I thought this is only for structs. Does it have any benefits over Marshal.Copy? Except obvious simplicity.

Comment: @matti Well, `double` *is* a struct, just like `int` or `Point`. `Marshal.Copy` is less safe - I'm not sure how you're using it, but it makes possible security (and reliability) issues more likely simply by providing a wider interface. And you still have to do the cast at some point - `Marshal.PtrToStructure` is simply a safer method that handles cases like unaligned values. How are you using `Marshal.Copy`? Whatever it is, it sounds like it's more dangerous than just using `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: @Luaan: of course it is a struct. my bad. somehow i mixed this up when I tried to misuse Marshal.PtrToStructure<double> with 2 parameters. now I use it properly. my way to use Marshal.Copy is in an answer I wrote below. However I changed it to your suggestion. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

In case dialogName and fieldName indicates it's double I do:

```
    private int ChangeFieldValue(string fieldName, IntPtr newValue)
    {
        double[] destination = new double[1];
        Marshal.Copy(newValue, destination, 0, 1);
```

any thoughts on this? Seems to work.

Comment: This *is* an interesting trick, though completely unnecessary :) There's going to be a few overheads over the straightforward approach (whether using unsafe code or `Marshal`) - you're allocating an array and it has to be pinned for the duration of the copy (which is very short of course, but...). Of course, those are tiny if you're not in a tight loop.